# Can a subfolder in Google Drive be visible to a user or group but its content hidden?

Tags: permissions, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

My scenario:

1. A script creates a common folder
2. A list of users (email addresses) are added as viewers (read permission) for this folder.
3. In this common folder, a subfolder for each user is added. The user is added as editor (write permission) for its on subfolder.

This user subfolder should be visible for all other users but not content of the subfolder.
(The above uses DocsList terms: viewer/editor)

As each user is viewer of the common folder the permission is inherited down to subfolders and their content, or?.

I think I'm looking for a possibility to 'remove' execute flag for the subfolders. I have looked in both `DriveApp` and `DocsList` but not yet found a way how to solve this.

My current script uses `DocsList`, which I find is easier to use when creating sub folder and setting permissions.  I can of course rewrite it to use DriveApp instead if that is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible to do it but you will need to always remove view and edit permissions from all items inside all subfolders (except for the person that matches the subfolder name).
All you gain is that now all users see the user's folders but they wont see anything inside. 
Wont be perfect because if later a user manually adds files to his folder those will inherit again the read permissions for all the other users. You could cover that case with a daily trigger that fixes all files again.

Answer (score 0):

if a folder is not shared it doesn't show up. What you're trying is not doable in the Drive Ui, I see no reason it would be possible with GAS. Did you try and get some results ?

Comment: In my current solution the owner can see all folders, but each user user can only see its own. For me that's good enough, now I need to convince the stake holders...

Comment: See my answer below. Its possible.

Comment: Yeah... I see... woaw... not specially easy but you're right it IS possible ;-)

Comment: yes, just wanted to mention it because it is actually useful in some cases, but its definitely not a practical thing to do.